# Unpickling and encoding a string using rdd.map in PySpark

Tags: python, hadoop, encoding, pyspark, rdd

I need to port code from PySpark 1.3 to 2.3 (also on Python 2.7 only) and I have a following map transformation on the rdd:

```
import cPickle as pickle
import base64

path = "my_filename"

my_rdd = "rdd with data" # pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD()

# saving RDD to a file but first encoding everything
my_rdd.map(lambda line: base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(line))).saveAsTextFile(path)

# another my_rdd.map doing the opposite of the above, fails with the same error
my_rdd = sc.textFile(path).map(lambda line: pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(line)))
```

When this part is run, I get the following error:

```
   raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Looks like actions like this are not allowed anymore in the `map` function. Any suggestion how to potentially rewrite this part?

UPDATE:

weirdly enough, just doing:

```
my_rdd.saveAsTextFile(path)
```

also fails with the same error.

Comment: Please provide the code that constructs `my_rdd`, including all transformations you're doing on it.

Comment: @SergeyKhudyakov so the error is somewhere in the transformations along the way? The problem is, that code is too big and not documented, is there a way I can force PySpark to point to the actual line that fails instead of pointing to the last operation on the rdd?

Comment: yes, I don't see any issues with the code you posted. Most likely, there's a transformation function in your code that references RDD, which is exactly what the exception tells you. Without seeing the full code, I don't think anyone will be able to help you. Actual line - you can try to insert a debug statement, e.g. simple `str(rdd)`, between the transformations you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line, the problem was somewhere deep in the functions doing the transformations. Easier to rewrite than debug in this case.